# Awk Subtract value from columns

Tags: awk, calculated-columns, subtraction

I need help with this in AWK. I would like to subtract value of the second column from  the first row from the first row from second column  (20 - 15, 40 - 35, 45 - 45, etc.)

INPUT FILE

```
 10   15 
 20   35 
 40   45 
 45   55 
 58   70
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
5
5
0
3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> cat numb

```
10   15
20   35
40   45
45   55
58   70
```

so to perform action

```
awk 'p{print $1-p}{p=$2}' numb
```

output

```
5
5
0
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {a=$2; next} {print $1 - a; a=$2}' file
5
5
0
3
```

#### Explanation

It keeps track of the 2nd value and stores in the variable `a`.

- `NR==1 {a=$2; next}` if we are in the first record (line), just store the 2nd col.
- `{print $1 - a; a=$2}` from that moment, print the difference between 1st column and stored value. Then, store the 2nd col of current line, to be used in the following line.